# Getting nil when trying to parse JSON consisting of an array in an array containing Null

Tags: json, null, alamofire, codable

I'm suffering for a week, you are my last hope, here is the JSON that I'm trying to parse, it comes from the server

```
[
  1,
  null,
  [
    {
      “categories” : [
        {
          “id” : 26,
          “category” : “sweaters”
        }
      ],
      “sellingPrice” : “6000.00",
      “statusSite” : “a”,
      “type” : “wear”,
      “id” : 30024,
      “payoutType” : “3”,
      “style” : “Avant Garde”,
      “count” : 1,
      “status” : “active”,
      “images” : [
        {
          “productId” : 30024,
          “image” : “2000000211176-066e7e39b0a590501fe85155a571258e.jpg”,
          “imageMin” : “2000000211176-a7e0626b3512f517f23b1e091224e759.jpg”,
          “name” : “6.jpg”
        },
        {
          “productId” : 30024,
          “image” : “2000000211176-25bc8175742d959448f0c8211d7753f6.jpg”,
          “imageMin” : “2000000211176-6212cd8a58a4e7269d282651eb316429.jpg”,
          “name” : “3.jpg”
        },
        {
          “productId” : 30024,
          “image” : “2000000211176-3bd4648416c5a1e525417673a0328060.jpg”,
          “imageMin” : “2000000211176-e3bf05a38f430013e9077637244e45b8.jpg”,
          “name” : “1.jpg”
        },
        {
          “productId” : 30024,
          “image” : “2000000211176-561ce49fbb4de29b8ef905f66279f432.jpg”,
          “imageMin” : “2000000211176-67f41b0a32e48a380d5b5d27c7dcaea8.jpg”,
          “name” : “4.jpg”
        },
        {
          “productId” : 30024,
          “image” : “2000000211176-c37ff0bd838d2f8eaabaa09e45a8b07f.jpg”,
          “imageMin” : “2000000211176-b6e96c3ff88965f301ade7257eb8653e.jpg”,
          “name” : “2.jpg”
        },
        {
          “productId” : 30024,
          “image” : “2000000211176-f3c14b80583e079d11b9fc5556af5f8b.jpg”,
          “imageMin” : “2000000211176-4907e8502f739b56579f53a5eaa8d0a9.jpg”,
          “name” : “5.jpg”
        }
      ],
      “priceInAct” : null,
      “additionallyHeldAmounts” : null,
      “vendorCode” : “000000238”,
      “amountOfCommission” : null,
      “searchWords” : “10sei0otto, ,dieciseizerotto,sweater ,Свитер ,Gently used,Отличное,Black,Черный,,“,
      “id1c” : “2000000211176",
      “brand” : {
        “name” : “10sei0otto”,
        “id” : 987
      },
      “saleStatus” : “A”,
      “tradeIn” : “N”,
      “composition” : null,
      “isHidden” : false,
      “created” : “2022-12-11T00:00:00.000Z”,
      “collections” : [
      ],
      “name” : “Black Leather Patched Sweater”,
      “userId” : 2312,
      “sex” : “M”,
      “imagesPath” : “[\“2000000211176_1.jpg\“,\“2000000211176_2.jpg\“,\“2000000211176_3.jpg\“,\“2000000211176_4.jpg\“,\“2000000211176_5.jpg\“,\“2000000211176_6.jpg\“]”,
      “badgeSale” : 0,
      “badge” : “{\“background\“:\“#FF00FF\“,\“image\“:\“https:\/\/toppng.com\/uploads\/preview\/sale-badge-sale-tag-symbol-11563037290rmf7mns4rx.png\“,\“text\“:\“\”}“,
      “features” : [
      ],
      “timestampPrice” : null,
      “condition” : “Gently used”,
      “place” : 1,
      “saleDate” : null,
      “languages” : [
        {
          “description” : “”,
          “discount” : “0.00”,
          “languageCode” : “en-EN”,
          “size” : “XL”,
          “price” : “170.00”
        },
        {
          “description” : “”,
          “discount” : “0.00”,
          “languageCode” : “ru-RU”,
          “size” : “XL”,
          “price” : “11000.00”
        }
      ],
      “userId1c” : “000000238”
    }
  ]
]
```

---

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var jsonResultsTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonLbl: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        buttonLbl.setTitle("PUSH", for: .normal)
        
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        
        AF.request("https://beta.server.spin4spin.com/auth/login", method: .post, parameters: login, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).response { response in
            print(response)
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func get(_ sender: Any) {
        if let urlString = URL(string: "https://beta.server.spin4spin.com/admin/raw-catalog?search=2000000211176") {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlString) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    print(data)
                    do {
                        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
                        print(responseJSON as Any)
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let json = try? decoder.decode([[Dats]].self, from: data)
                        print(json as Any)
                    } catch let error {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}


struct Dats: Codable
{
    let integer: Int
    let null: String?
    
    struct ResponseClass: Codable
    {
        struct FinalClassArray: Codable
        {
            let sellingPrice, statusSite, type: String
            let id: Int
            let payoutType, style: String
            let count: Int
            let status: String
            let vendorCode: String
            let searchWords, id1C: String
            let saleStatus, tradeIn: String
            let isHidden: Bool
            let created: String
            let name: String
            let userID: Int
            let sex, imagesPath: String
            let badgeSale: Int
            let badge: String
            let condition: String
            let place: Int
            let userId1C: String
        }
    }
}
```

It throws a Nil error when trying to decode the values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGcd4.png)

Tried using Alamofire, SwiftyJson nothing helps to avoid errors

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the root object is a **heterogenous** array, which cannot be decoded synthesized. This is very unusual and cumbersome.

You have to implement `init(from decoder:` and decode each item in the array *manually*. I'm talking about `Decodable`, `SwiftyJSON` has become obsolete.

And there are three properties which don't match the keys, `id1c`, `userId` and `userId1c`  (note the different lowercase and uppercase characters)

These structs match the given JSON

```
struct Dats: Decodable
{
    let integer: Int
    let null: String?
    let items : [FinalClassArray]
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var arrayContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        self.integer = try arrayContainer.decode(Int.self)
        self.null = try arrayContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self)
        self.items = try arrayContainer.decode([FinalClassArray].self)
    }
}
    
struct FinalClassArray: Decodable
{
    let sellingPrice, statusSite, type: String
    let id: Int
    let payoutType, style: String
    let count: Int
    let status: String
    let vendorCode: String
    let searchWords, id1c: String
    let saleStatus, tradeIn: String
    let isHidden: Bool
    let created: String
    let name: String
    let userId: Int
    let sex, imagesPath: String
    let badgeSale: Int
    let badge: String
    let condition: String
    let place: Int
    let userId1c: String
}
```

And this is the code to decode the data (I renamed the function `get` as `loadData`)

```
 @IBAction func loadData(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://beta.server.spin4spin.com/admin/raw-catalog?search=2000000211176") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
        if let error { print(error); return }
            
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Dats.self, from: data!)
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```